# Triggering Click Event will Retrun true but will not work

Tags: javascript, automation

Here is a target for the test:

https://demo.wpjobboard.net/wp-login.php

I need to click on login button using javascript and I use this peice of code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id="wp-submit"]')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

I need to use `dispatchEvent` because the `click` event here can be replaced with any event.

It will return `true` but it won't work. where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query selector all will return a list of dom nodes, you should probably use just document.querySelector, but even better probably is document.getElementById since you are querying via ID.

Addtionally there is a simpler click event method available. What about something like this:

```js
function checkBox(){
    document.getElementById('wp-submit').click()
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="wp-submit" type="checkbox">
  <button type="button" onClick="checkBox()">
    Click me to check the box
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: as you see in my code `document.querySelectorAll('[id="wp-submit"]')[0]` I have seleteced the first element. The problem is with `dispatchEvent`